# What characters are valid in PGP encrypted and signed messages?

Tags: encryption, signature, pgp

What characters may be present in a PGP encrypted message or a PGP signature? For example, do encrypted messages only use the Roman alphabet + some numbers and symbols? Can the character set be configured by the user? Is everything Base64 encoded?

Also, are there special characters that will never be used in a message?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OpenPGP as defined by [RFC 4880](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880) knows two different encodings.

#### Binary encoding

Obviously, there is no reasonable limitation to an (ASCII) character subset in binary encoding.

#### Radix 64

[Radix 64](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-6) is also often called *ASCII armored*. In the end, it is a base64 encoding with a checksum. The content [may consist of `[a-zA-Z0-9+/=]`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-6.3).

ASCII-armored OpenPGP messages also include a header, which [may contain arbitrary UTF-8 strings](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#page-56).

An example message in ASCII-armor (modified from the one in the RFC):

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
Version: OpenPrivacy 0.99
Comment: An example for an UTF-8 string with arbitrary characters

yDgBO22WxBHv7O8X7O/jygAEzol56iUKiXmV+XmpCtmpqQUKiQrFqclFqUDBovzS
vBSFjNSiVHsuAA==
=njUN
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```